# Calculating Recessions and Recoveries of quarters

Tags: python, pandas

Given this dataframe

```
   GDP quarter
0  250  2015q1
1  260  2015q1
2  250  2015q3
3  240  2015q4
4  250  2016q1
5  260  2016q2
```

How can I figure out what quarters are recessions and what quarters are recoveries?

A Recession is when GDP is decreasing two quarters in a row

A Recovery is when GDP was decreasing, but is now on the rise.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you have a question? Can you show your attempts

Comment: Also please avoid posting dataframes as pictures, always include them as text so it's easy to test the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here you need to use the Series.shift function

Since your data is not easily copypastable, I'll just create my own example data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"quarter":["2015q1", "2015q1", "2015q3", "2015q4", "2016q1", "2016q2"], "GDP": [250, 260, 250, 240, 250, 260]}
df['Last_GDP'] = df.GDP.shift(1)
df['Increase'] = df.GDP > df.Last_GDP
df['Last_Increase'] = df.Increase.shift(1)
df.ix[(~df.Last_Increase.fillna(False) & ~df.Increase), 'Re-x'] = "Recession"
df.ix[(~df.Last_Increase.fillna(False) & df.Increase), 'Re-x'] = "Recovery"
df.ix[df.Last_Increase.isnull(), 'Re-x'] = "Unknown"

   GDP quarter  Last_GDP Increase Last_Increase       Re-x
0  250  2015q1       NaN    False           NaN    Unknown
1  260  2015q1     250.0     True         False   Recovery
2  250  2015q3     260.0    False          True        NaN
3  240  2015q4     250.0    False         False  Recession
4  250  2016q1     240.0     True         False   Recovery
5  260  2016q2     250.0     True          True        NaN
```