# Getting the quarter where recession start and recession ends along with the quarter of minimum gdp

Tags: python, pandas

```
Quarter:    GDP:   GDP change:  change
1999q3     9           --         ------
1999q4    10           1          increase
2000q1     9          -1          decline
2000q2     8          -1          decline
2000q3     7          -1          decline
2000q4     6          -1          decline
2001q1     8           1          increase
2001q2     11          3          increase
2001q3     12          1          increase
```

Here is the Processed dataFrame Now I need separate list of all the quarters in which recession starts ,recession ends and bottom of recession

The start of recession in the example above is '2000q1'because the GDP decline started then

recession end is ''2001q2'

recession bottom is '2000q4' because it has the minimum GDP between start and end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find two consecutive quarters of GDP decline, and ending with two consecutive quarters of GDP growth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361537/find-two-consecutive-quarters-of-gdp-decline-and-ending-with-two-consecutive-qu)

Comment: This is a really popular question lately (homework question?).  Here's another one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537655/pandas-determine-the-start-end-and-bottom-of-recession-based-on-gdp?rq=1

Comment: Yes, this is part of Assignment 4 of "Introduction to Data Science in Python" on Coursera.  Students in that course are encouraged to use Stack Overflow.  They lack the common sense to not post the questions verbatim, however.

Comment: This is probably wrong: "The start of recession in the example above is '2000q1'because the GDP decline started then".  Most definitions of the start of recession specify "two down consecutive quarters of GDP".

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41849806.  It's almost the same question, from the same user, asked a day earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .loc attribute after setting the quarter the index of the dataframe.

```
Df.loc[start:end]
```

You can make the quarter the index of the dataframe using the following statement

```
Df = Df.set_index('quarter')
```

Hope that helps.

As asked by you how can you find the recession start and other parameters. Here is the code you can use:

```
for index in df.index:
      first_q = df.loc[index, 'gdp']
      second_q = df.loc[index+1, 'gdp']
      third_q = df.loc[index +2, 'gdp']
```

Now the logic is : (if second_q < first_q) and (third_q < second_q) then the first_q is the recession start.

And similarly if second_q > first_q and third_q > second_q then third_q is the recession end.

Basically recession start is the presence of 2 consecutive gdp decline years and recession end is the presence of two continuous GDP increase years

Comment: Actually the problem is how I can find which quarter is recession start quarter and which is corresponding recession end quarter

Answer (score 0):

```
recession_start = False
recession_gdp = 0
quarter = {'start': None, 'end': None, 'min': None}
min_gdp = 10000


final_list = []


for i, row in frame.iterrows():

    if row['change'] < 0 and not recession_start:
        recession_start = True
        recession_gdp = frame[i - 1]['gdp']
        quarter['start'] = row['quarter']

    if row['gdp'] < min_gdp and recession_start:
        min_gdp = row['gdp']
        quarter['min'] = row['quarter']

    if recession_start and row['gdp'] >= recession_gdp:
        quarter['end'] = row['quarter']
        final_list.append(quarter)
        # reset all values
        recession_start = False
        recession_gdp = 0
        quarter = {'start': None, 'end': None, 'min': None}

        min_quarter = None
        min_gdp = 10000
```

final_list has the final answer. I'm sorry I do not know pandas and there may be some errors. This is more like a brief algorithm.. but you can get it right with just a little refactoring. Hope it helps you!..

Also I'm assuming the recession ends when the gdp is equal to or greater than the gdp 'just before' the recession started which in your example is 10.