# Pandas detecting consecutive negative numbers in a row, and returning values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this, and I need to extract the Quarter where two consecutive negative change values occur. Eg. 2000q4. It has to be the Quarter of the first negative Change, not 2001q1

I also need the last quarter of the first two positive quarters after to negative quarters eg 2002q1

```
         Quarter    GDP  Change
Quarter                         
2000q1   2000q1  12359.1     NaN
2000q2   2000q2  12592.5   233.4
2000q3   2000q3  12607.7    15.2
2000q4   2000q4  12679.3   -71.6
2001q1   2001q1  12643.3   -36.0
2001q2   2001q2  12710.3    67.0
2001q3   2001q3  12670.1   -40.2
2001q4   2001q4  12705.3    35.2
2002q1   2002q1  12822.3   117.0
2002q2   2002q2  12893.0    70.7
2002q3   2002q3  12955.8    62.8
2002q4   2002q4  12964.0     8.2
```

Ive tried using apply, and where. Apply did not work because I could not use shift.

```py
df['bool'] = df['change'].where(df['change'] < 0).where(df['change'].shift() < 0)
```

The results I am expecting are 2000q4 and 2002q1

Comment: What happen if there's a streak of more than 2 quarters where GDP growth was negative? Do you want to return only the first quarter in the streak?

Comment: probably a duplicate as there are a few versions of this recession indicator question lying around stack overflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361537/find-two-consecutive-quarters-of-gdp-decline-and-ending-with-two-consecutive-qu?noredirect=1&lq=1 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875744/getting-the-quarter-where-recession-start-and-recession-ends-along-with-the-quar?noredirect=1&lq=1 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849806/calculating-recessions-and-recoveries-of-quarters?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: also there are lots of prior pandas questions about techniques for detecting consecutive values in general.  For example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555036/pandas-flag-consecutive-values

Comment: @CodeDifferent yes only the first quarter. Thank you

Comment: @JohnE I had a hard time finding an answer on stack overflow. Some of the solutions your linked use looping, and I was really trying to stay away from that. At least one of your solutions was a great alternative, I just did not find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to verify the conditions correctly:

```
cond1=(df['Change'].shift(1)>0) & (df['Change']<0) & (df['Change'].shift(-1)<0)
cond2=(df['Change'].shift(2)<0) & (df['Change'].shift(1)>0) & (df['Change']>0)
cond = cond1 | cond2
df1=df[cond1] #to show the rows that verify the condition1
df2=df[cond2] #to show the rows that verify the condition2
```

**Now if you want to save in a `df['bool']`  the values ​​that verify the coding use:**

```
df['bool']=df.loc[cond,'Change']
```

Also you can use `where`:

```
df['bool'] = df['Change'].where(cond)
```

---

Output df1,df2:

```
df1

         Quarter.1      GDP  Change
Quarter                           
2000q4     2000q4  12679.3   -71.6
```

---

```
 df2

        Quarter.1      GDP  Change  
Quarter                                               
2002q1     2002q1  12822.3   117.0
```

---

Output `df`:

```
        Quarter.1      GDP  Change   bool
Quarter                                  
2000q1     2000q1  12359.1     NaN    NaN
2000q2     2000q2  12592.5   233.4    NaN
2000q3     2000q3  12607.7    15.2    NaN
2000q4     2000q4  12679.3   -71.6  -71.6
2001q1     2001q1  12643.3   -36.0    NaN
2001q2     2001q2  12710.3    67.0    NaN
2001q3     2001q3  12670.1   -40.2    NaN
2001q4     2001q4  12705.3    35.2    NaN
2002q1     2002q1  12822.3   117.0  117.0
2002q2     2002q2  12893.0    70.7    NaN
2002q3     2002q3  12955.8    62.8    NaN
2002q4     2002q4  12964.0     8.2    NaN
```

`df[cond]`

```
        Quarter.1      GDP  Change   bool
Quarter                                  
2000q4     2000q4  12679.3   -71.6  -71.6
2002q1     2002q1  12822.3   117.0  117.0
```