# How can i make a function to find the period of Recession start and Recession bottom in GDP dataframe.(Definition of Recession given.)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe composed of State and RegionName as index and columns depicting quarter period of a year and that year in order.e.g 2000q3 means 3rd quarter of 2000. The values in the cells are GDP values for that region in that particular period.

```
State        RegionName   2000q1     2000q2     2000q3     2000q4      2001q1    ..........
NewYork      NewYork     
California   Los Angeles  207066.67  214466.67  220966.67  226166.67   233000.00 ..........
Illilois     Chicago      138400.00  143633.33  147866.67  152133.33   156933.33 ..........
Pennsylvania Philadelphia 53000.00   53633.33   54133.33    54700.00    55333.33 .......... 
...........  ..........   ........   .......    .......    .........   ......... ..........
```

I need to write a function such that for each row the function: For each row i.e. for each region, I need to find the quarter of Recession start and Recession bottom and put them in new columns named "Rec_start" and "Rec_bottom".

RECESSION: A recession is defined as starting with two consecutive quarters of GDP decline,and ending with two consecutive quarters of GDP growth. A recession may also have more than two consecutive quarter of decline but the recession must end with two consecutive quarters of growth.

RECESSION BOTTOM: A recession bottom is the quarter within a recession which had the lowest GDP.

For example: `a>a+1>a+2>a+3>a+4` and `a+4<a+5<a+6` than period corresponding to `a+1` is RECESSION START because from here onwards GDP starts decreasing. `a+4` points to Recession Bottom and `a+6` points to recession end as it completes two consecutive quarters of growth.

Ratio = GDP(quarter just before recession start)/GDP(quarter having recession bottom) 
Here is what i tried to code:

```
col=df.columns.tolist()
df=df.apply(ratio,axis=1,colo=col)  

def ratio(row,colum):

    for i in range(1,len(colo)-3):
        if(row[colum[i]]<row[colum[i-1]]) and (row[colum[i]]>row[colum[i+1]]) and (row[colum[i+1]]<row[colum[i+2]]) and (row[colum[i+2]]<row[colum[i+3]]):
          # Checking the condition for Recession
            for j in range(1,i):
                if row[colum[i-1-j]]>row[colum[i-j]]: 
                    continue  #Now tracing back to where Recession started
                else: 
                    if row[colum[i-1-j]]<row[colum[i-j]]:
                        row['Rec_start']=row[colum[i-j+1]] #Recession start
                        row['Rec_bottom']=row[colum[i+1]]  #Recession bottom
                    break
            break 
    return (row)
```

I had made my own function using for loops and applied that to each row using pd.Apply method, but i am getting wrong values of ratios. Can somebody help me in making a correct function which can perform the task i mentioned above? If there is anything not clear in this question, Please just ask me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question, as well as a list of things that are [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Open-ended questions or general requests for guidance are not allowed - if you have tried to implement this but are running into a bug, please share your code and be specific about what isn't working and why. Be sure to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks!

Comment: It looks likes your question (almost exact) has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843425/pandas-detecting-consecutive-negative-numbers-in-a-row-and-returning-values

Comment: @moys Thanks for the suggestion but that question has different condition as that consists of quarters as index for a single Region but in my question each row represents a different region and columns represent quarters and in each row GDP of that region is given quarterwise. So it requires some different approach i think.I have also included the function i used.

Comment: Thanks for editing suggestion. I have also included the function which i was using for this problem.Now its more clear i think.  @Michael Delgado

Comment: If your code does not raise errors, but also does not accomplish the analytical task you're hoping for, then it is off topic for stack overflow. Check out [quantitative finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

**Input**

```
St  Rg  12q1    12q2    12q3    12q4    12q5    12q6    12q7    12q8    12q9    12q10
xy  xy  20        21      19    18        16    14        12    13        14    15
ab  ab  45        46      47    48        45    44        45    46        43    47
de  de  100       99      98    66        55    44        22    11        12    13
ef  ef  45        44      46    47        42    41        40    44        43    45
```

**Code**

```
a = df.set_index(['St','Rg']).diff(axis=1)
a[a<0]=-1
a[a>=0]=1
a[a==1]=0
a[a==-1]=1
a[~(a.shift(axis=1)==1)&~(a.shift(-1,axis=1)==1)]=0
rs = a.idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True).reset_index(name='Rec_strt')
rb = a.gt(0).cumsum(axis=1).idxmax(axis=1).reset_index(name='Rec_btm')
pd.merge(pd.merge(df,rs,on=['St','Rg']),rb,on=['St','Rg'])
```

**Output**

```
St  Rg  12q1    12q2    12q3    12q4    12q5    12q6    12q7    12q8    12q9    12q10   Rec_strt    Rec_btm
xy  xy  20      21      19      18      16      14      12      13      14      15          12q3    12q7
ab  ab  45      46      47      48      45      44      45      46      43      47          12q5    12q6
de  de  100     99      98      66      55      44      22      11      12      13          12q2    12q8
ef  ef  45      44      46      47      42      41      40      44      43      45          12q5    12q7
```